# Method does not exist or incorrect signature

Tags: apex, unit-test

```
@isTest private class cSearchTest{
@isTest static void testbuildQuery(){
    Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Standard User'];

     User u = new User(alias = 'standt', email='standarduser@testorg.com',
     emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
     localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id,
     timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='standarduser@testorg.com');

     System.runAs(u){
         //system.debug(conSearch.buildQuery());
         system.debug('Tree Types are: ' + conSearch.getTreeType());
     }

}

}
```

The above code causes the error:

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature: conSearch.getTreeType()

The code from the conSearch controller

```
public class conSearch {

public PageReference doFilter() {
    return null;
}

public List<Tree2__c> sTree {get;set;}
public String searchString {get;set;}

public Tree2__c tSurgeon {get;set;}

public String searchType {get;set;}
public String searchDisease {get;set;}
public String searchSurgeon {get;set;}
public String searchStatus {get;set;}
public boolean searchBreed {get;set;}
public Date searchDate {get;set;}

String startQuery = 'SELECT TreeID__c, Tree2__c.Name, Status__c FROM Tree2__c WHERE Native_Breed__c = :searchBreed';
List<String> query = new List<String>();
public String testQuery {get;set;}

public void buildQuery(){
    Date phDate;
    searchSurgeon = tSurgeon.Surgeon__c;

    String tyQuery = 'Type_of_Tree__c LIKE :searchType';
    String diQuery = 'Disease__c LIKE :searchDisease';
    String suQuery = 'Surgeon__c = :searchSurgeon';
    String stQuery = 'Status__c LIKE :searchStatus';
    String daQuery = 'Date_of_planting__c = :searchDate';
    String brQuery = 'Native_Breed__c = :searchBreed';

    query.add(startQuery);

    if(searchDisease != null){
        query.add(diQuery);
    }
    if(searchSurgeon != null){
        query.add(suQuery);
    }
    if(searchStatus != null){
        query.add(stQuery);
    }
    if(searchDate != phDate){
        query.add(daQuery);
    }
    if(searchType != null){
        query.add(tyQuery);
    }

    String result = String.join( query, ' AND ' );
    sTree = Database.query(result);
    testQuery = result;
    query.clear();
}

public void clear(){
    sTree.clear();
}

public conSearch(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
    rTreeType = (Tree2__c) controller.getRecord();
    rDisease = (Tree2__c) controller.getRecord();
    rStatus = (Tree2__c) controller.getRecord();

    tSurgeon = new Tree2__c();
}

//**-------------------------------------------populate picklist values-------------------------------------------**//
Tree2__c rTreeType;
Tree2__c rDisease;
Tree2__c rStatus;

public List<SelectOption> getTreeType(){
    List<SelectOption> treeType = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Tree2__c.Type_of_Tree__c.getDescribe();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry ple : dfr.getPicklistValues()){
        treeType.add(new SelectOption(ple.getValue(), ple.getLabel(), !ple.isActive()));
        if(ple.isDefaultValue()){
            rTreeType.Type_of_Tree__c = ple.getValue();
        }
    }
    return treeType;
}

public List<SelectOption> getDisease(){
    List<SelectOption> disease = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Tree2__c.Disease__c.getDescribe();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry ple : dfr.getPicklistValues()){
        disease.add(new SelectOption(ple.getValue(), ple.getLabel(), !ple.isActive()));
        if(ple.isDefaultValue()){
            rDisease.Disease__c = ple.getValue();
        }
    }
    return disease;
}

public List<SelectOption> getStatus(){
    List<SelectOption> status = new List<SelectOption>();

    Schema.DescribeFieldResult dfr = Tree2__c.Status__c.getDescribe();
    for(Schema.PicklistEntry ple : dfr.getPicklistValues()){
        status.add(new SelectOption(ple.getValue(), ple.getLabel(), !ple.isActive()));
        if(ple.isDefaultValue()){
            rStatus.Status__c = ple.getValue();
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

}

Am i incorrectly calling the class? As far as I can this is the correct way to call the method in a unit test.

Comment: can u share ur complete code including the actual class you are trying to test.. where is this object conSearch being created ?

Comment: If getTreeType is not a static method you need to instantiate the class first before you can call the method. Please post all relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

In your test you will need to instantiate the class. This will require a Standard Controller as well. So to get started your test will look like this:

```
@isTest private class cSearchTest{
@isTest static void testbuildQuery(){
    Profile p = [select id from profile where name='Standard User'];

     User u = new User(alias = 'standt', email='standarduser@testorg.com',
     emailencodingkey='UTF-8', lastname='Testing', languagelocalekey='en_US',
     localesidkey='en_US', profileid = p.Id,
     timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles', username='standarduser@testorg.com');
     //Instantiate class here with default Tree2__c object
     conSearch con = New conSearch(New ApexPages.StandardController(New tree2__c()));

     System.runAs(u){
         //system.debug(conSearch.buildQuery());
         system.debug('Tree Types are: ' + con.getTreeType());
     }

}

}
```

You will need to ensure the New Tree2__c() part is instantiated with the values you require. This does not address any other potential issue so if this answer solves the stated problem mark it as answered and **create a new question for any other issues that arise.**